# Very last exit point of application

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012

I need to write a function that exits my application and thereafter shuts down Windows 7.

I already got the code for exiting my application (this.Close() in the main form) and for shutting down Windows (shutdown.exe with various parameters).

This question is not related to the correctness of the above ways of exiting and closing.

My question is:
Obviously I need to call shutdown.exe AFTER closing my application, so what is the very last event that is called, where I should put my Windows shutdown code?
My guess would be at the end of FormClosing event, but is this correct?

I'm using .net framework 4.5.

Other suggestions are welcome to achieve the above.

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the [ProcessExit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.processexit%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) event of AppDomain:

```
static void OnProcessExit (object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Process.Start("shutdown", "/s /t 00");
}
```

Comment: I ended up using this one as I like the idea of using an event.

Answer (score 1):

Ah, no, totally wrong.

See......

Your application starts with Application.Run (someform). THis makes the then current thread (the one that starts the application) Register as message loop for the form and process the events of it.

When this ends (forms are all closed), this statement continues with the next line.,

So you can just do your work at the end of the main mehod, right after Application.Run (). No need for events.

Your application has a core entry method like this:

```
public static void Main(string[] args) {
    // Starts the application.
    Application.Run(new Form1());
 }
```

And you can just add logic before and - in your case - after the Application.Run call.

Comment: Then I guess I would need Application.Run(new Form1()) to return a boolean value to determine whether Windows is to be shutdown?

Comment: @JohnSaps No. If you need that then a global varialbe may help, possibly as a configuration block you create before and then put into the form.

Comment: Thanks, maybe I'll need this approach for other projects :)

Answer (score 0):

Another way would to go is to just initiate shutdown — the Windows will send your program a shutdown notification which by default leads to your program exitting.

Comment: That should be a comment as it not represent actual answer.

Comment: I already thought about this way, but I'd like to control the closing of my application myself.

Comment: @JohnSaps What kind of "control" do you mean?

Comment: I meant that I don't have the overview about what happens when Windows forces an application to close.

Comment: @JohnSaps When Windows shuts down, it just sends a message to every application. By default, this message is processed by an application just as clicking at the "Close" button or Alt+F4 would be. It's only if the application doesn't end in 20 seconds, it will be shown as preventing shutdown, and IIRC after another 20 seconds it will be terminated.

Comment: OK, thanks for the explanation! My application actually performs some file saving stuff when closing, which takes about 30 seconds to end.

Answer (score 0):

look here
use Process.Start("shutdown",  /t /s /0");

http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/480049/Shut-Down-Restart-Log-off-or-Lock-your-computer-in